# Is there a way to change Visual Studio 2022 performance analyzer session output files location?

Tags: visual-studio, performance, visual-studio-2022

How to make Visual Studio 2022 write performance analyzer session for C++ project to another location than %TEMP%?

Having large amount of data produced during VS2022 performance analyzer I want to specify another disk for its intermediate/output files.

I see that in the [Allow users to change performance analyzer output files location](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/allow-users-to-change-performance-analyzer-output/617593) feature request has been released in 17.0, but I can't see the way to manage this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Microsoft documentation on [Optimizing Profiler settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/profiling/optimize-profiler-settings?view=vs-2022):

> You can specify a different scratch directory by first opening the Diagnostic Tools Window (Debug > Windows > Show Diagnostic Tools), and then choosing Select Tools > Settings > General > Scratch Directory.